# Use a value for a Postgresql setting in a trigger

Tags: postgresql, trigger, transaction

We're using a trigger to track changes in various database tables. This works fine. Now we want to be able to track the changes back to the web request that caused them.

I'd like to be able to use `SET LOCAL` for this, because it will also serve as a useful check that a transaction has been properly created. So the idea is to insert a row in a requests table and then use `SET LOCAL pubsubpull.request_id` to set the ID for the request which can then be used in the `INSERT` statement in the update log table generated in the trigger (if available).

I can see what the value is using `SHOW pubsubpull.request_id`, but how do I capture that value so it can be used in the `INSERT` table? `SHOW` doesn't seem to be legal in `SELECT` in any way. These user defined options don't seem to show up in the `pg_settings` view so I can't select it from there.

I have looked at using `txid_current()` but would prefer not to need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `current_setting`:

```
SELECT current_setting('pubsubpull.request_id');
```

Comment: Thanks -- Google is next to useless for searching for a keyword like `SHOW` :)